# Using And & OR condition in MySQl With Same Query

Tags: mysql

How to use the And, OR condition in the same MySQL where query.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name
WHERE filed_name = 0 AND (field1 != '' AND field2 ='')
OR (field1 = '' AND field2 != '') AND filed3 = 1;
```

I want to more than 2 fileds in brackets.

Comment: You can use as many fields as you want in brackets. Give it a try.

Comment: `AND` takes precedence over `OR` so as your query is written you don't need any parentheses at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include as many conditions as you need within parentheses, but you do need to be careful with `OR` and you may find it necessary to combine multiple sets of conditions with parentheses. When this happens consistent formatting and use of indents can help you maintain the required logic.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_name
WHERE (field_name = 0 
  AND (field1 != '' AND field2 ='')
      )
OR  (field3 = 1
 AND (field1 = '' AND field2 != '')
      )
;
```

Do note that the query above is a guess; I have assumed you need 2 sets of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

SQL refer to columns  (not at fields) 
anyway you can use all the columns you need in each where condition

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table_name
    WHERE col0 = 0 
    AND col1 != '' 
    AND col2 =''
    OR (col1 = '' AND col2 != '' AND col3 ='YOUR_VALUE') 
    AND col3 = 1
    OR (col4 = 'your_value4' AND col5> 100 );
```

the parentheses are needed for change the priority in evalaution of the condition  ...